# Omsnx plot has transparent background

Tags: python, matplotlib, osmnx

There is a new version of osmnx and when I try to plot my graph with my color bar the image I get has a transparent background. In earlier versions this did not happen. Can anyone explain me why this transparent background appears?

**Here is the code:**

```
city = 'Portugal, Lisbon'
G = ox.graph_from_place(city, network_type='drive', simplify=True)
G_nx = nx.relabel.convert_node_labels_to_integers(G)
G_1 = ox.project_graph(G_nx)
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('inferno_r')
norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=min_r, vmax=max_r)
sm = mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap)
sm.set_array([])

fig, ax = ox.plot.plot_graph(G_1, node_color=nc, node_size=ns, edge_linewidth=0.5, figsize = (40,40), bgcolor = 'white')
cb = fig.colorbar(cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap), ax=ax, orientation='horizontal', aspect=30, fraction = 0.2)
cb.set_label('r', fontsize = 60)
cb.ax.tick_params(labelsize=60)
fig.savefig('demo1z.png')
```

***Please consider the node colors a random list since this is just an example, the same goes for the node size.***

**Here is the image:**

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OSMnx constrains the fig/ax size to the specific plotting area. If you extend the size of the plot by adding additional features such as a colorbar, just turn the figure frame on and give it a facecolor when you save it.

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)

# get graph
city = 'Lisbon, Portugal'
G = ox.graph_from_place(city, network_type='drive', simplify=True)

# get colors
cmap = 'plasma'
nc = ox.plot.get_node_colors_by_attr(G, attr='y', cmap=cmap)
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=min(nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'y').values()),
                            vmax=max(nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'y').values()))

# plot graph and add colorbar
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, edge_linewidth=0, node_size=1, node_color=nc, show=False, bgcolor='lightgray')
cbar = fig.colorbar(mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap))

# turn figure frame on and save to disk
fig.set_frameon(True)
fig.savefig('fig.png', facecolor=fig.get_facecolor(), bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was unfamiliar with figure frame